# Error in MediaPlayer - setOnCompletionListener()

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am getting error in the some android devices at setOnCompletionListener(this). Please let me know which one is correct.

1. setOnCompletionListener() before start().

   ```
   private void playBackGround() {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
       backGround.reset();
       backGround.release();
       backGround = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.bgm);  
       backGround.setOnCompletionListener(this); 
       backGround.start(); 
   }
   ```
2. start() before setOnCompletionListener().

   ```
   private void playBackGround() {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
       backGround.reset();
       backGround.release();
       backGround = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.bgm);  
       backGround.start(); 
       backGround.setOnCompletionListener(this); 
   }
   ```

**Log Cat :**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at memory.game.collection.free.Start.playBackGround(Start.java:665)
at memory.game.collection.free.Start.onCompletion(Start.java:679)
at android.media.MediaPlayer$EventHandler.handleMessage(MediaPlayer.java:2019)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5006)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```